# make a diamond text pattern

Tags: python

I am trying to make a diamond text pattern using Python, but I am a little stuck on how to get the shape I want.

I found this project in python that looks like this:

[image: project]

The code for this output is here:

```
word=input("Enter characters: ")
length=len(word)
for i in range (0, length,2):
    for j in range(length-i//2):
        print(' ', end="")
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        print(word[j], end="")
    print()

for i in range (length - 3,-1,-2):
    for j in range(length-i//2):
        print(' ', end="")
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        print(word[j], end="")
    print()
```

But now, I want to make this pattern from that code that looks like this:

INPUT: project

[image: project]

INPUT: japan

OUTPUT:
[image: japan]

It kinda looks like a rough sketch but it depends on the string input of the user, where integer or string, and it will print these kinds of patterns. The formatting kinda looks like the mentioned output of the code at the top.

Hopeful that you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shot at it.  Basically keeping track of a counter for spacing and an enumerator for justifying.

```
word=input("Enter characters: ")
s = 0
for i, l in enumerate(word):
    if s==0:
        print(l.rjust(i+len(word)))
        s+=1
    else:
        print((f'{l}{" "*s}{l}').rjust(i+len(word)))
        s+=2
s-=2
for i, l in reversed(list(enumerate(word))[:-1]):
    if s==1:
        print(l.rjust(i+len(word)))
        s-=1
    else:
        s-=2
        print((f'{l}{" "*s}{l}').rjust(i+len(word)))
```

Output

```
Enter characters:  awesome
      a
     w w
    e   e
   s     s
  o       o
 m         m
e           e
 m         m
  o       o
   s     s
    e   e
     w w
      a
```